# Não estou conseguindo somar números no python

Tags: python

Boa noite pessoal, comecei recentemente a aprender python e já recebi um exercício par fazer, só que lá pede para criar um programa que consiga somar 2 números e dar um resultado.

Eu tentei igual o meu professor disse, mas o resultado não sai igual uma conta normal.
Exemplo: 1 + 1 = 11
Acontece isso com qualquer número que coloco.

Aqui meu código

```
print('Bom dia')
n1 = input('Insira um valor: ')
n2 = input('Insira ou valor: ')
n3 = n1 + n2
print(f'O resultado da sua soma é {n3}.')
```

Answer (score -3):

Boa noite Diego!
Acabei de olhar o seu código e já sei o que pode estar acontecendo.
O jeito que você criou o programa para poder fazer somas, você está utilizando o `input` do jeito que só recebe letras, e não números.
Para resolver isso, tente colocar `int()` antes do `input`, pois com ele você estará indicando que o `input` receba só números.
Ai, o seu código deverá ficar assim:

```
print('Bom dia')
n1 = int(input('Insira um valor: '))
n2 = int(input('Insira ou valor: '))
n3 = n1 + n2
print(f'O resultado da sua soma é {n3}.')
```

Desse, jeito o seu código funcionará perfeitamente como deseja, vale lembrar que o `int()` no `input` faz com que ele só receba números, caso colocar alguma letra, ele irá dar erro.
Também, por padrão, o valor do `input` já vem recebendo letras, como no caso de seu código.
Isto é tudo o que sei, tomara que te ajude e bons estudos!